# Set a global variable with eval or exec in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, eval

Let me start by saying I completely agree that you should
[keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)
but let's pretend you wanted a function like this:

```
def setglobal(s, x):
  # Some kind of eval or exec trick like eval(s+' = '+x) so we end up
  # with a global variable whose name is the string s and that has a value of x.
```

Comment: You could also maintain one global dict to which you add key s and value x.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion, what is your interest in having a function like this?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say! :) Ok, I'll try to give a sense of it: I have a dictionary of a couple dozen parameters for an API and I do a whole mess of calculations with them such that it would be tedious to always refer to them like `p['foo']` instead of just `foo`. Does that sound crazy, or like I'm probably going about things all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be an exec/eval trick?

```
def setglobal(s, x):
    globals()[s] = x
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
# Take a symbol name s as a string and a value x and eval(s+' = '+x) to set a 
# global variable with name s to value x. For getglobal(s) use eval(s).
def setglobal(s, x):
  exec "global "+s+"; "+s+" = "+repr(x) in globals()
```